# create a non unique relationship between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to understand how to have a relationship for a table that does not require a primary key as the values will likely be repeated.#

My concern is that within the "failed_table" it will feature an error code and I want this error code to have a relationship with another value which takes the error code and has a description of the error code. But within the failed table there could be multiple instances of the same error code too? I just want the error code to be able to point to another table which will have further information. I attempted to set the 'Error_code' in the 'failed_table' as a PK so i can create a FK to point to it but I'm not sure how else to create this type of relationship? Like a non unique value relationship.

Mainly so if I was able to query the failed_table I could find further info about what type of error code it means from a separate table

[image]

Comment: In `error_table` the `Error_code` should be unique. You're storing the error code and its message at only one place. In `failed_table`, `error_code` should be the foreign key pointing toward the `error_table`

Answer (score 0):

Logically you have a 1:n relationship, that is, there could be many instances of the same error type. There are two things to clarify:

- while you are not technically forced to define a `primary key`, avoiding the creation of a primary key is a bad idea and violates the norm of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), which is a bad idea (unless you know what you are doing and have a reason for it) as it does not enforce rules that guarantee you will not end up with inconsistencies
- a foreign key does not have to be unique, for instance, if you have a table for companies and another for employees, while the employees have a foreign key of company_id pointing to the id of a company record, that's perfectly fine even if multiple employees are working for the same company

With all that in mind, you need to have a `primary key` for `error_table`, at least on a conceptual level. A handy way would be to convert `Error_code` into a `primary key`, but it is a habit to create an automatically incremented numerical id instead. You can create such an ID like below

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
```

Whatever the `primary key` you end up with, you will be able to create a `foreign key` toward it from `failed_table`. The main difficulty you will have is to determine which `error_table` record to point to, if the code can be repeated.

EDIT

Tested adding an `auto_increment` `primary key` as follows:

```
create table foo(bar varchar(1));
insert into foo values('a'),('b');
alter table foo add column id int auto_increment;
select * from foo;
```

Result

[image]